# DTExec will not run without a window

Tags: c#, process, ssis, utility, system-calls

I am running SSIS from a C# application.  I would like to run the SSIS process using the dtexec utility but without showing the dtexec window when running.  I have set the ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow to true yet dtexec still displays the window.  I assume this is due to dtexec and not C#, but I cannot find a argument for dtexec that will keep it from displaying the window.  I am hoping somebody knows a way to keep the dtexec window from displaying when it is running.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it's always shown.

It can be quite disconcerting at first when it pops up: even worse when you click it and freeze your job+ scheduling accidently...

Comment: Bummer but not unexpected.  I was able to tell .NET to show the window but to run minimized.  Evidently SSIS will only open its own window if the calling window is not visible.  Using this technique made an acceptable look.  Thanks.